# How to send WhatsApp message to a specific contact in Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, android-intent, firemonkey, whatsapp

This code, written in Delphi with FireMonkey, calls WhatsApp which sends images and text after selecting the contact:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent : JIntent;
  Uri    : Jnet_Uri;
  Uris   : JArrayList;
  Path   : String;
begin
  Path := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath+PathDelim;
  Image1.Bitmap.SaveToFile(Path+'1.png');
  Image2.Bitmap.SaveToFile(Path+'2.png');
  Image3.Bitmap.SaveToFile(Path+'3.png');
  Uris   := TJArrayList.Create;
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND);
  Intent.setPackage(StringToJString('com.whatsapp'));
  Intent.setType(StringToJString('text/plain'));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT, StringToJString('Texto de teste'));

  Uri := TJNet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(Path+'1.png'));
  Uris.add(Uri);
  Intent.setDataAndType(Uri, StringToJString('image/png'));

  Uri := TJNet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(Path+'2.png'));
  Uris.add(Uri);
  Intent.setDataAndType(Uri, StringToJString('image/png'));

  Uri := TJNet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(Path+'3.png'));
  Uris.add(Uri);
  Intent.setDataAndType(Uri, StringToJString('image/png'));

  Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM, Uris);
  Intent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

My question:
How to send directly to the contact provided?

Comment: My experience leads me to believe you cannot send direct to a contact using intents - it will always prompt you to select which one.